# Product: Aptana Studio -- Error 4155. Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi

Tags: javascript, installation, aptana

I’ve installed the latest official node.js but I’m getting an installer error that it can't acquire node.js.

Does anyone know if this is a bug and if there’s a workaround? Right now I cant get Aptana to install.

Comment: Have you tried running the installer as administrator?

Comment: I ran into the same issue because I had the 64 bit version of Node.JS installed and Aptana needs the 32 bit version.

Comment: @Irdial, have any of the answers below worked for you?  If so, please choose an answer.  tia

Comment: Check this solution, it works https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935360/7720102

Answer (score 99):

<strike>Install this: http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows and then run the Aptana installer again.</strike>

UPDATE:
Link seems to be dead. Go to node.js homepage and download it from there.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Does this affect my previous installation of nodejs on my computer? I have already nodejs installed.

Comment: It shouldn't. Also, if you already have nodejs, you shouldn't have any problems installing aptana.

Comment: I've installed a more recent version of Node.js but It didn't work.
It worked with the executable of your link.

Comment: worked for me. Just know that your computer might not want to run the program, saying it is "unsafe." in this case I ran it anyway. :) Also, I had the newer version of node.js installed. Install this one anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This worked fine. Still don't know why, but it works!

Comment: When I downloaded the latest version (v8.4.0) from https://nodejs.org/en/download/, it did not work. I then tried the link mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924272/4660897) and downloaded node from https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.13/ and it worked.

Answer (score 29):

To start work with `Aptana Studio`, just extract it from archive to your folder by command:

```
Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1.exe /extract:"folder"
```

Launch:

```
AptanaStudio3.exe
```

And enjoy without `nodejs_windows.msi`

Answer (score 19):

Issue appears to be with the installer itself. I can't get Aptana installed on any new systems including ones that had it previously installed.

You can use this install Aptana without node.js or git

```
Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1 /passive /norestart
```

Comment: Issue has been reported see [APSTUD-8436](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8436)

Comment: AWESOME answer.. This fixed my issue, while the others didn't. Note however, that it doesn't create ANY icons anywhere EXCEPT one on your desktop.

Answer (score 4):

(May 29 2017)

Just go download and install Nodejs from this URL:

http://titanium-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/nodejs/node-v0.10.13-x86.msi

After I did that Aptana installed properly for me!

EDIT:

> Another issue that I had is that Aptana couldn't start due to the following issue: `Failed to load the JNI shared library C:/JDK/bin/client/jvm.dll`. That was because I had Java JDK 64 bits, but Aptana is x86 so it would complain about it until you install Java 32 bits.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16259322)

Comment: Thanks @Frits! I think that if the link changes for some reason, people could just google for "node-v0.10.13-x86.msi" and I bet some alternatives could be found. In my case I made it to that URL by searching "http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows" on the webarchive site "https://web.archive.org/"

Answer (score 3):

I tried Orejano's suggestion and the install succeeded. The installer did not revert my current version, instead installed another Node.js app published by Joyent, Inc (https://www.joyent.com/services/nodejs-support).[image]

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem while installing Aptana. Go to `my computer` and in the search button write `installer_nodejs_windows.msi`. It leads you to one search which is something like `windows installer`. Please click it and install the node that has been already provided to you rather than installing it by yourself. In this way, after a series of installation, set up the aptana and proceed accordingly. It gets installed.

Answer (score 2):

I installed an earlier version of Aptana Studio from http://www.filehorse.com/download-aptana/19350/.  I then updated with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just install eclipse and download the "Eclipse Plug-In Version." I had the same problem and this was a quick work around.