# Failed to correctly acquire intaller_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error

Tags: node.js, aptana

I am getting an error:

```
Failed to correctly acquire intaller_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error.
```

When trying to install `Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1.` I also installed `node-v4.2.1-x64.msi` (restarted the system)  and `Git-2.6.2-64-bit`, but still not able to install and getting the above error. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514458/cannot-install-aptana-studio-3-6-on-windows has similar fixes. Something there may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Product: Aptana Studio -- Error 4155. Failed to correctly acquire installer\_nodejs\_windows.msi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364694/product-aptana-studio-error-4155-failed-to-correctly-acquire-installer-node)

Answer (score 69):

I wasn't able to locate installer_nodejs_windows.msi on my PC, so I downloaded it separately from here: http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows

After installing Node JS for Windows, I was able to successfully install Aptana.

Note: Above link no longer seems to be working.  Looks like you can download Node JS separately from here: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.13/

Comment: What a dreadful piece of CXXP Aptana turns out to be: 1) you can't install the plugin in Eclipse (BROKEN, BROKEN, BROKEN); 2) this standalone comes up with this annoying error; 3) it is reliant on a technology like nodejs, which is simply not a mature, stable technology; 4) finally, when I get it to install (thanks to you) it insists on cr**ping up my C: drive with yet another version of git (I have no option to install it on another drive).  Enough.  Aptana, GOODBYE.

Comment: I first tried downloading the latest version of node (v8.4.0) from https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/ and it didn't work. I then downloaded the version from https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.13/ and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

The current version of Aptana requires a Node version between 0.8.X and 0.11.X. I recommend a 0.10.X version of Node.

The next release (in November) will allow compatibility with Node 4.2.1.

Comment: Downloading and installing Nodejs 0.10.13 for Windows 10  https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.13/ still made the trick for me (7/31/2017)

Answer (score 6):

Basically, create the folder you want to extract **Aptana** to, and then use this command:

```
Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1.exe /extract:"folder"
```

Comment: Thank you for these instructions. This step worked for me. I have node.js installed, ran as administrator, and still got same error. I only had to modify your step to use absolute path to folder as relative did not work.

Comment: DIDN'T WORK 2017-05-29 (W10)

Answer (score 2):

This is a cut and paste from an earlier entry and it worked for me.

Go to my computer and in the search button write installer_nodejs_windows.msi. It leads you to one search which is something like windows installer. Please click it and install the node that has been already provided to you rather than installing it by yourself. In this way, after a series of installation, set up the aptana and proceed accordingly. It gets installed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Aptana Studio setup file and click "Run as Administrator". Worked for me.

Its is most probably the lack of admin rights that is preventing Aptana setup from making changes to your computer by installing nodejs, git, etc prerequisites.

Comment: DIDNT WORK 2017-05-29 (W10)

Answer (score 0):

The latest node.js versions wouldn't work for my Aptana, but an older version did which I found [here](http://titanium-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/nodejs/node-v0.10.13-x86.msi),

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using following steps

1. Rename installation file as aptana.exe
2. Copy and paste aptana.exe into c drive
3. Open cmd with Run as administrator
4. In cmd write command C:/aptana.exe /passive /norestart (Put space before /passive and /norestart)

[image]