# Aptana Studio error on install

Tags: installation, aptana, aptana3

I'm trying to install Aptana Studio 3 version: 3.6.1.

But this error comes up:

[image]

I have installed

The .NET Framework version 4.5.2 and Node.js.

I don't know if that will help, but I tried downloading those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check here , prior [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398769/failed-to-correctly-acquire-intaller-nodejs-windows-msi-file-crc-error), [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.0/) is where I found the 10.0 ver.

Uninstall the version of `node.js` you currently have and install 10. 
It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of node.js at: http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows 
then run the aptana installer again