# Aptana Install Node.js failing to download

Tags: installation, aptana

Aptana studio 3 won't finish installing because it can't download the node.js msi file. I went and downloaded it separately, but that didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to correctly acquire intaller\_nodejs\_windows.msi file: CRC error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398769/failed-to-correctly-acquire-intaller-nodejs-windows-msi-file-crc-error)

Answer (score 0):

The Aptana installer creates a folder in "User name/AppData/Roaming/Appcelerator".
The folder is named "Aptana Studio 3.6.0".

In Appcelerator, create a new folder named "Aptana Studio" (without the quotation marks.)

Re-run the installer.

If it creates the node.js msi file in a subfolder, double click on it and it will install the node.

Re-run the installer.  It should automatically download and install the prerequisites folder and files, including Git.

Aptana then correctly completes the install.

It appears the key to solving the install problem is creating the correct name for the install folder in "User name/AppData/Roaming/Appcelerator"

Answer (score 0):

When I checked in the directory, the "Aptana Studio" folder was already there. I ended up following [this thread's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040970/aptana-studio-3-6-installation-error) instead, and it worked.

Also, my apologies for asking an existing question: my search prior to asking came up empty, even though it should have found it. Not sure why not, though...