# Aptana studio 3.6 installation error

Tags: node.js, installation, aptana

When trying to install Aptana Studio 3.6.1 (on WinXP) I get an error: 
"Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error".

I downloaded node.js windows installer from nodejs.org and installed it, but next trial to install Aptana failed. I copied the file to "/AppData/Roaming/Appcelerator/Aptana Studio/installer_nodejs_windows.msi", but next Aptana installation trial failed with the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

Aptana Studio 3.6 doesnt work with the newest version of node.js. I had the same problem. When i installed older version it worked. Here is a link: http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows
I hope to work!

Comment: It didn't resolve the problem. Installation of Aptana was not completed.

Comment: You should add the path of node.js in the system variables/path.