# Aptana 3 (3.6.1) Will Not Load on my Windows 10 Laptop

Tags: node.js, windows-installer, windows-10, aptana, crc

I know you all heard similar complaints, yet no response has worked for me through browsing these questions and answers. Please forgive me if you believe this to overly repetitive.

1. Loaded Node.js (4.2.2) first tried 32bit, and later tried 64bit installer.
2. Attempted to load Aptana studio 3 (3.6.1) but got an error.

### "Failed to acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error."

I have tried updating environmental variables, and loading the 64bit instead. I have uninstalled, reinstalled, rebooted, etc. I like this application on my school computer, and really want to give it a try at home. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Installing node first as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364694/product-aptana-studio-error-4155-failed-to-correctly-acquire-installer-node) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am also using windows 10 and encountered same error. Download and Install the file http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows manually and then run aptana installer. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Same error. Install Node js

Install Node JS:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/